# how to use sched_yield() to synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The following are parts of the codes, 
In my idea, the program should run as this. In vows(), if the words is not vows, the program will run sched_yield() command, and then switch to the cons thread. However, the result is not like that. vows cannot switch to cons thread even sched_yield() was called.

Comment: That's not how threads work. Sounds more like you're looking for [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

Comment: sched_yield() doesn't necessarily yield to your programs other thread, it will yield to all running threads